# What is the difference between creatable vs. updatable on Schema.DescribeFieldResult

Tags: apex, describefieldresult, fls, describes

When writing CRUD and FLS checks in apex I have noticed that I can check for the following:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = field.getDescribe();
fieldDescribe.accessible;
fieldDescribe.createable;
fieldDescribe.updateable;
```

The check for accessible is self explanatory but what is the difference between creatable and updatable since the FLS configuration on a profile only allows Read and Edit?

[image: Profile FLS access]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many fields cannot be changed once populated, such as **Audit Fields**. Run this script:

```
for (SObjectField field : SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().values())
{
    DescribeFieldResult describe = field.getDescribe();
    if (describe.isCreateable() != describe.isUpdateable())
    {
        system.debug(field);
    }
}
```

You should see something like:

> CreatedDate
>   CreatedById
>   LastModifiedDate
>   LastModifiedById
>   IsCustomerPortal

---

Another circumstance where there would be a discrepancy is a **Master-Detail relationship which does not allow reparenting**.

[image: Reparentable Master Detail (false)]

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the quick answer - makes perfect sense.